# tap on image should open dialog boxes in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have an image so when I tap on the image it should open me a dialogue box with two buttons saying Camera or Gallery so the user can select to choose whether he wants to take a picture from camera or use already existing image from gallery.

I m using GestureListener to listen to Tap event.

```
    <Image Margin="88.687,189.769,58.674,340.698" Grid.Row="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto" Source="feet,vintage,music,girl,girl,guitar,jeans-7285bdf005743617f8892359619b148a_h.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform Rotation="-8.33"/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
        <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
            <toolkit:GestureListener Tap="GestureListener_Tap" />
        </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
    </Image>
```

But I dont know how to invoke the dialogue box if the user tap on the image. Or Is it possible I could use context menu to select camera or gallery.

please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a `ContextMenu` you should use the `ContextMenu` from the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com) as you're already attempting to use for the GestureListener.

Then you can assign two different commands, one for opening the `CameraCaptureTask` or another for opening the `PhotoChooserTask`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the **Gesture Listener**, you can just add an *event handler* to the ***Tap*** event of the *image control*.

```
 < Image Tap = "MyImageTap" name="MyImage"> < /Image>
```

from the **XAML**. Or you can do the same in **code** by:

```
MyImage.Tap += new RoutedEventHandler(MyImageTap);
```

Then in the event handler function, you can perform the desired logic.

For presenting a pop-up, you can use the default **Popup** control, or can create your own control, as per your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply .Could you please let me know how to create my own Custom Popup Control

Comment: Using Expression Blend you can design your pop-up and then convert the same in a control.